# git when working on open source projects

Tags: git

I am working on git for quite some time now and I have some questions that I am putting below:

1. Git compresses all the source code on the local machine in an efficient manner. For projects that we work on it might be simple to understand, but I want to know when working on a massive project especially on open source where there are thousands of developers working on many parallel releases, will such enormous codebase be stored the same way on the local machine. Even I feel that such projects cannot be using Centralized VC for sure. Please let me know your thoughts on the same.
2. I have an option to switch to a particular revision of the codebase using the `git checkout` command. Once I switch to the revision, If I make changes and commit, how to handle this scenario since it has deviated from the commit history which it was earlier pointing to.
3. In what real time scenario we use the `commit amend` feature and what we need to take care when amending a commit.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: Yes GIT should be used. Git has a very sophisticated algorithm not only for compressing the content, but also for saving the contents which only have been changed. It is not important for Git that how many files do you have, the only things which matters to git the the CONTENT, that is why it is primarily targeted toward handling big chunks of data.

Anyway, you should know about git functionalities and how to utilize them when encountering problems. For instance, some problems which one might bump into in large projects, is the long history of changes, numerous branches etc. You may want to make your history shallow, or apply filters to your branches etc. For a more throughout explanation, you may want to read http://blogs.atlassian.com/2014/05/handle-big-repositories-git/

Question 2: If you are going into a temporary branch, for instance `temp_branch_001`, after committing the changes, you should `checkout master`(or the branch which is treated as master) and then `git merge temp_branch_001` to keep your main branch up to date. Nevertheless, if your branch is a permanent branch with a totally different content, then there might be no need for the master branch to be merged into.

Question 3: You use it to enhance previous commits with your new changes, rather than making a new commit. For this one you can refer to a comprehensive explanation here: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Regarding the first question, that means, there are thousands of developers committing to linux os and many branches and all these can be efficiently handled using Git. Can centralized repository even be imagined to be used in such scenarios where it need to support this kind of requirement?

Comment: Well, at least several years ago they were used. But old tools were for old time. Managing (logically) centralized repos is easier. But anyway, a git master should be considered in serious scenarios, and NO, avoid using centralized repos if you know using GIT. Since git, if applied correctly, adds high level of discipline to your project which would help you later on in the project, not to mention flexibility, cost reduction and efficient algorithm for handling content changes with robust compressing capabilities.